# How do I get Port level granularity when using Pulseaudio?

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, sox

I'm trying to remove noise from a mic.

`pacmd list-sources` shows `analog-input-mic` and `analog-input-internal-mic` However when i run `pacat` it only allows a device-spec `name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>` How do I get the granularity of a port.

The command I'm trying to stitch together is
`pacat --format=s16le --channels=2 -r -d $input --latency=1msec|sox -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -r 44100 -t raw - -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -r 44100 -t raw - noisered noise.prof 0.2|pacat -p -d $output --latency=1msec&`

Why are most of the examples I'm seeing online, specifying the entire card and not CARD-index-name:PORT. I generally find myself fiddling with `ALSA` or `pavucontrol` to set the specific PORT i need?

I did further googling and found this:
[Pulseaudio Profiles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348823/how-to-force-pulseaudio-ports-to-be-available) Apparently you can set the cards 'active profile' but this is global and will affect all apps.In my case, I have `active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>` so I can't change to `analog-input-mic:` without creating a profile AND it'll affect any further apps that I start. Also found this [PulseAudio Architecture Overview](https://gavv.github.io/blog/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/) 
`A card represents a physical audio device` `It also has a single active card profile` `A card profile represents an opaque configuration set for a card.` `Only one card profile of a card may be active at the same time. The user can switch the active card profile at any time.`

`The user can switch the active device port of a source or sink at any time.`
but when I do alsamixer -c 0 and change the `Input Source` it doesn't affect pulseaudio in any way. Pulseaudio continues to show `active port: <analog-input-mic>` instead of `analog-input-internal-mic` (using `pacmd list`)

Comment: currently I'm doing: pactl set-source-port  alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  analog-input-mic to switch to analog-input-mic